# ActiveX control for sharepoint integration

Tags: sharepoint, activex

I am working on integrating web parts on sharepoint. After reading many articles I found developing an ActiveX control would be an approach for such integration.

But an ActiveX control would be required only if you want to access windows features (hardware interaction) like accessing webcam or mic from your GUI. If this kind of interaction is not required, then a simple web parts in jquery or java can be developed without any activeX control. These jquery or java components can be integrated with Sharepoint and can call any third party webservices to be displayed on sharepoint pages.

Please confirm what I understood is correct. Any other suggestion would be great to have.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX control is a terrible idea unless you have to do something that absolutely can't be done with html, javascript etc - and in which case you should still consider Silverlight/Flash first.

You can add arbitrary javascript to a SharePoint page in a number of ways - content editor web part, edit master page, delegate controls, custom web part.

More details.

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/adding-javascript-and-css-to-sharepoint.html

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/sharepoint-how-to-add-javascript-to.html

Comment: Ok. Let me add a use case: Suppose I have a web page and contains link and I want if some user performs mouseover on that link, an UI should be shown. So is it possible to add something like this on any external web page with html, javascript?

Comment: UI - what sort of UI and is the site something you can add javascript to? Do you want to highlight something? Do something like skimlinks. Not enough detail in your 'spec' but probably (almost certainly) can do that with JavaScript.

Comment: UI can be a simple javascript/JQuery UI which will show presence information of user (shown as link on the sharepoint page) using some webservice call. Sharepoint pages are normally aspx pages and I want to integrate some UI on mouseover etc. to some link generally userlink.

Comment: Yes. Javascript/Jquery, no need for ActiveX

Comment: But such script should be dynamically loaded by the sharepoint page, isn't it? How to do this integration i.e. integrating my custom UI script page with the Sharepoint page which is an aspx page.                   In case of ActiveX or custom DLL, I can attach it to each IE instance for eg. and display my UI without placing anything on serverside. But yeah client side would have this dll on there machine which is not good.

Comment: I think you should close this Q and ask it in a much clearer fashion with more detail over on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/